# "undefined reference to 'main'" : main.o created but main function not compiled

Tags: c, gcc, linker

Please note that as this question is related to my work, I would like to give as few as necessary information about my program.

I am trying to compile a program for a RISC-V microcontroller. I am using the GCC RISC-V compilation tools.

The project contains several files together with a '*main.c*' file, which contains a basic '*main*' function (empty for now):

```
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

During compilation, I am getting the following message from the linker:

> riscv-none-embed/bin/ld.exe : in startup.S : undefined reference to
> 'main'

I've checked, and the compiler has produced an object file for the *main.c* file: *main.o* . But the '*main*' function does not appear inside it; when running the **nm** tool on *main.o*, I'm getting this output :

```
0000018e t .L0
00000196 t .L0
0000019c t .L0
000001a4 t .L0
000001aa t .L0
000001c2 t .L0
000001c4 t .L0
000001c8 t .L0
000001ce t .L0
000001ce t .L0
00000076 t .L4
00000104 t .L5
000001e7 N .LASF0
000001ac N .LASF1
00000224 N .LASF10
000000e1 N .LASF11
.
.
.
00000469 N .LASF57
000000e9 N .LASF58
00000151 N .LASF59
0000008a N .LASF6
000004a2 N .LASF60
0000026c N .LASF61
00000000 d some_global_variable
00000000 T some_function0
0000017c T some_function1
00000110 T some_function2
00000050 T some_function3
         U some_function4
         U some_function5
```

Please note that all of the *'some_functionX'* and the global variable were not defined in *main.c* but in others C-files.

Here is my Makefile (to be correct: the main part of it, I've removed the confidential parts):

```
STARTUP_FILE := $(ROOT_DIR)/../startup.S
STARTUP_OBJ := $(ROOT_DIR)/../startup.o

TOOL_DIR := $(ROOT_DIR)/../../riscv_gcc/riscv-none-embed-gcc/bin
GCC         := $(TOOL_DIR)/riscv-none-embed-gcc-10.2.0
LD          := $(TOOL_DIR)/riscv-none-embed-ld
GDB         := $(TOOL_DIR)/riscv-none-embed-gdb
OBJCOPY     := $(TOOL_DIR)/riscv-none-embed-objcopy
OBJDUMP     := $(TOOL_DIR)/riscv-none-embed-objdump
READELF     := $(TOOL_DIR)/riscv-none-embed-readelf
CODESIZE    := $(TOOL_DIR)/riscv-none-embed-size 
NMINFO      := $(TOOL_DIR)/riscv-none-embed-nm


LIB := $(LIB_DIR)/lib$(TARGET).a
ELF := $(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf
BIN := $(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET).bin
HEX := $(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET).hex
DASM := $(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET).dasm

EN_OPTIMIZE = -O0
OPTFLAGS    := -march=rv32imc -mabi=ilp32 -mno-strict-align --specs=nano.specs $(EN_OPTIMIZE)
AFLAGS      := -D__STACK_SIZE=$(STACK_SIZE) -nostartfiles --entry Reset_Handler
LDFLAGS     := $(LINKER_FILE) -Xlinker -Map=$(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET).map -L$(LIB_DIR)
LDFLAGS     += -falign-functions=4 -falign-jumps -falign-loops -falign-labels
# The -MMD flags additionaly creates a .d file as header dependency with the same name as the .o file.
CFLAGS      := -g -Wall -MMD -Wtype-limits -Woverflow -Wabsolute-value -Wno-unused-label $(INC_DIR) $(EN_OPTIMIZE)
CFLAGS      += -falign-functions=4 -falign-jumps -falign-loops -falign-labels -mno-relax




.PHONY: all
all: $(ELF) $(BIN) $(HEX) $(DASM)


# build object files
$(OBJ): $(SRC)
ifeq ($(wildcard $(OBJ_DIR)),)
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
endif
    $(GCC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@



# Build the library .a 
$(LIB): $(OBJ)
ifeq ($(wildcard $(LIB_DIR)),)
    mkdir -p $(LIB_DIR)
endif
    $(TOOL_DIR)/riscv-none-embed-ar -crs $@ $(OBJ)


# Build .elf
$(ELF): $(LIB) $(OBJ)
ifeq ($(wildcard $(BIN_DIR)),)
    mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
endif
    $(GCC) $(CFLAGS) $(STARTUP_FILE) $(LDFLAGS) $(AFLAGS) -l$(TARGET) -o $@


# Build .bin
$(BIN): $(ELF)
ifeq ($(wildcard $(BIN_DIR)),)
    mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
endif
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@


# Build .hex
$(HEX): $(ELF)
ifeq ($(wildcard $(BIN_DIR)),)
    mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
endif
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $< $@


#Build disassembly file .dasm
$(DASM): $(ELF)
ifeq ($(wildcard $(BIN_DIR)),)
    mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
endif
    $(OBJDUMP) -d -S $< > $@



.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(OUTPUT_DIR)
```

Please let me know if more information is required.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Install eclipse, add your toolchain and forget about manual makefiles.

Comment: You're _not_ showing the values for `GCC`, `STARTUP_FILE`, etc. You're using `$(TOOL_DIR)/riscv-none-embed-ar` so I would expect `GCC` to be defined similarly. Also, you have `-MMD` in `CFLAGS` that build the `.o/.elf` files. I could be wrong, but, I've always used `-MMD` _only_ when creating a `.dep` file and not when creating `.o` files or `.elf` files. Perhaps you should edit your question, and post the _output_ of your `make` command in a separate code block.

Comment: @CraigEstey I've added info about GCC and STARTUP_FILE. Regarding the -MMD, I must admit that I don't really know how it works, it was added by someone else. But we have been using this flag for several times and it wasn't an issue until now.

Comment: @CraigEstey, I had to look it up, but unless `-E` is also specified, `-MMD` generates dependency files *in addition to* object files.  Some of the other `-M` directives differ on that, though.

Comment: Since `startup.S` is where the complaint is, perhaps post that? Since you're trying to build for bare metal, that would be important. Also, the linker script. And, again, the _output_ of the [running] `make` command? You may get more/better info from `readelf -a` than `nm`

Comment: Your makefile is too big to interpret in my head. Please post the exact commands as they are invoked by `make`.

Comment: Having said that, the line `$(OBJ): $(SRC)` looks very wrong. All objects depend on all sources, but you have just one command to run to build them all? I don't think it can work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule

```
$(OBJ): $(SRC)
        $(GCC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

will compile (only) the first source file in $(SRC), and do that repeatedly for each object file in $(OBJ).  Assuming you have mulitple source and object files, all the .o files will end up being the same -- the result of compiling that first source file.  This seems consistent with your nm output of main.o as some other source file is actually being compiled to get that, not main.c

What you actually want is a rule more like

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
        $(GCC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

this is a pattern rule that makes each file matching the pattern on the left depend on the pattern on the right, and will compile each source file to produce the corresponding object file.

Comment: That was the issue, now it works thank you very much